# Angular Check child component has finished async data from parent component

Tags: angular

I have a child component which uses an async pipe to format data which takes a bit of time. So I would like to check from parent component if the child component has finished loading.

Is there any lifecycle hooks or other strategies I could use in parent component to get notified that everything is loaded in the child component.

Comment: Can you please supply some code indicating where you are so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `@Output()` decorator on an `EventEmitter` that the parent component can hook to use.  This is detailed in the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Here is the example code from that documentation.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-voter',
  template: `
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    <button (click)="vote(true)"  [disabled]="didVote">Agree</button>
    <button (click)="vote(false)" [disabled]="didVote">Disagree</button>
  `
})
export class VoterComponent {
  @Input()  name: string;
  @Output() voted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  didVote = false;

  vote(agreed: boolean) {
    this.voted.emit(agreed);
    this.didVote = true;
  }
}
```